# Installing existing Jenkins as a Windows Service

Tags: jenkins

We currently have two existing and long standing Jenkins instances that are not currently installed as a service. The desire is to get them installed as a service on their host machines. I have found and read the documentation on how to do that.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service

My question is not particularly about how to do it, that appears to be simple enough. My concern is all the existing jobs and configurations that are there. Will they be effected by installing as a service? Will I need to essentially setup the Jenkins instance again? Are there any recommended precautions i should take? I currently have backups of each Jenkins instance, in case i need to back out. I'm hoping that someone out here as converted existing Jenkins setups to run as a service and can help ease my worries about losing the existing setups.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?  I want to do the same thing.  I'm worried because it asks for a new Jenkins home location...